# Unable to exit loop

Tags: python, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a program that finds the combination of denominations that can be used to represent that price without any denomination being repeated. The logic is simple but im unable to exit this loop in my code

```
Denom=[1]
Final_Price=int(input("Enter the maximum price"))
current_number=2
while(current_number<=Final_Price):
  present_number=current_number
  i=1
  while(present_number!=0):    ##problematic loop
    try:
      a=Denom[-i]
      print("current denom = "+str(a)+"\npresent number = "+str(present_number)+"\ncurrent number = "+str(current_number))
      if(Denom[-i]<=present_number):
        present_number=present_number-Denom[-i]
    except IndexError as exception:
      if(present_number!=0):
        Denom.append(current_number)
        present_number=0
        break
      else:
        present_number=0
        break
    print(i)
    i=i+1
  current_number=current_number+1 ##program has not reached this
```

I tried using break function that didnt work so I tried force the while loop condition to become false. What exactly is going wrong here

Sample output:

```
Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines.
27230
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27231
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27232
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27233
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27234
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27235
current denom = 2
present number = 1
current number = 3
27236
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not breaking out of the inner while loop?

Comment: look at the print statement in the try block i used that try to debug what went wrong. The current_number value is not increasing and the i value just keeps increasing. Wait a minute I will add a sample output to the post

Comment: What value are you entering for max price in your test? And do you have evidence that the IndexError is actually being thrown?

Comment: The max price value I am using for the test is 10. Yes IndexError is being triggered, suppose the current_number value is 2 the inner loop should run once. which would subtract 1 then the value of i would be incremented to 2 at this point the list Denom only has 1 element and thus would trigger an index error when Denom[-2] is called.

Comment: Yeah.... I found what went wrong. I used google colab to run the code and put the denom list declaration and the final_price value input in different cells from the cell where the actual processing was taking place. Because of my bad internet, the page had to refresh and I forgot to rerun the first cell... thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone I found what went wrong. I was using a python notebook on google colab and put the first 2 lines of my code in a separate cell from the rest. The solution was just to rerun both the cells.

For my fellow beginners remember to check if all cells have run when using an python notebook especially if you use an online compiler